# Refresh Navigation Drawer after Login

Tags: android

I have an App. After app launch, show the home screen. I am using Navigation Drawer. There is Login menu item in drawer. If they want to do same activities, user need to login.

Example, user choose login, show the login activity. After login, back to home page. Then reopen the drawer, I want to change the login to logout. May I know where do I refresh the drawer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If  they are different Activities, onResume in your Activity where is your Navigation Drawer.
If they are not you can do it onDrawerOpened.

```
@Override
   public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
   super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
  }
```